# How to save an Excel file via VB 2010 without any dialogs (such as "save as")

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel

I am trying to Save an Excel file Via VB 2010, and I have these questions

1. How can I disable the "save as" dialog? I tried things such as only "save" instead of "save as", but it doesen't work...
2. After I saved the file (using the save as) I can't Delete it... (I tried closing the excel file, Visual basic etc...) all i get is an error saying it is allready open in excel...
3. Is there a way to make VB show me the tips for writing the excel stuff (Ie - when I write messagebox. - it pops up "Show" for help. how can I enable this for excel code [worksheets.cells. ect.])

**the connection:**

```
Sub Connect()
    ' Connect to the excel file
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'Devine the  workbook
    oBook = oExcel.workbooks.open("e:\Words\Heb.xls")
End Sub
```

**the saveas:**

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    oExcel.SaveAs(oExcel.Path & ".xls")
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Excel VBA?

Answer (score 4):

I think Inafiziger has solved your main issue, it should be a vanilla `Save`.

As it was unclear to me exactly what your are doind (ie Visual Studio/VB/BA) then

On (1)

I thought it worth clarifying that you can use code *inside* the `ThisWorkbook` module to detect and handle a `SaveAs` if you are providing users with a choice. This Event detects the `SaveAs` and cancels it

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        MsgBox "You cannot use SaveAs to save this file", , "Save Cancelled!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code can be programmatically added to your target workbook but I doubt you would need to resort to this given you should be able to run the simple `Save`.

On (3)

You need to use [Early Binding](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/excel-vba/early-late-binding/) to get the benefit of `intellisense`. You are currently use late binding with `oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. A commonly used approach is to write the code and get it working with early binding, then converting it to late binding for final code publication.

[Conditional Compilation](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/take-advantage-of-intellisense-when-writing-late-bound-code/) (see comment at bottom) can be used to switch between the two binding methods within the same code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be saving the workbook.  e.g. `oBook.Save`.

If you create a new file, you will need to use `SaveAs` with a valid filename in order to save it the first time.